# Strange behavior in Rails 4.2.0.beta2 - Is this a bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

## Get a 500 error on **every other** window reload.

`assets/application-CACHE-.js` not found. No Idea what is causing it. Development environment. Using Unicorn as my webserver. Anyone know what this is?

```
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /blog HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.2885
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /about-64845c436e75ac587deec98177291d4e.css?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0110
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /blog-14053fca722628f43031ae06cb18c52c.css?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0110
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /contact-64845c436e75ac587deec98177291d4e.css?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0112
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /layouts/partials/footer-71929e4ed77e723296d6a937e6469653.css?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0116
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /portfolio-64845c436e75ac587deec98177291d4e.css?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0133
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /layouts/partials/navigation-1d28f98b6c63feaf0bd6b06fb5873475.css?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0136
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /resources-64845c436e75ac587deec98177291d4e.css?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0130
17:07:13 web.1  | Rack::Lint::LintError: Content-Type header found in 304 response, not allowed
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/lint.rb:20:in `assert'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/lint.rb:651:in `block in check_content_type'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/lint.rb:647:in `each'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/lint.rb:647:in `check_content_type'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/lint.rb:58:in `_call'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/lint.rb:37:in `call'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/showexceptions.rb:24:in `call'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/chunked.rb:54:in `call'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:576:in `process_client'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:670:in `worker_loop'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:525:in `spawn_missing_workers'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /resume-64845c436e75ac587deec98177291d4e.css?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0139
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /welcome-64845c436e75ac587deec98177291d4e.css?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0138
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /jquery-6a50177757f6c64493882fb7aae952c3.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0148
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /bootstrap/affix-04c58ad484d0bdbdf9514b7d09505d25.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0141
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET %2Fassets%2Fapplication-2e47777fcdd4d7b3353ccfc1718b4f0c.css?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 68784 0.0266
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /bootstrap/button-c9d4d44342d7be7abeb23fb0edbe00b7.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0219
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /bootstrap/carousel-b0f1e7b56803d98d500f5ccc15d550e3.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0150
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /bootstrap/alert-8186e091f2fa7c9423e9cadae6ce4de4.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0258
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /bootstrap/collapse-417aacb8b3257798b481ed397b421b7c.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0158
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /bootstrap/tab-dec75af9b2ffeed03dc43eabdb771d48.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0123
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /bootstrap/dropdown-f5a24e96d563b9a6d252c1c07a6ecc6b.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0142
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /bootstrap/modal-82015eda5031618c5aba3ebf9fc2cf4b.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0123
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /bootstrap/transition-3005c626234d995c29e4bcbd07b3ac0c.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0138
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /bootstrap/scrollspy-f421d662af4612a610656bfeee3407d9.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0140
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /bootstrap-sprockets-99470846ba99b7073a929a36d4cee32a.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0139
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /bootstrap/tooltip-5e9e765caafcbcb1672a3e72ef7f4a3a.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0158
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /bootstrap/popover-df8ed104d2525bbc4b4dad060e68cf99.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0211
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /jquery_ujs-03cb26c4b41579fc5e95ea8f47ac5e18.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0148
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /turbolinks-ebcce04d6463d2d77b51c18291df6925.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0162
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /about-32740fa4bc301ff5ef2eca5d8d82335a.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0140
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /blog-32740fa4bc301ff5ef2eca5d8d82335a.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0145
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /contact-32740fa4bc301ff5ef2eca5d8d82335a.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0164
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /portfolio-32740fa4bc301ff5ef2eca5d8d82335a.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0178
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /resources-32740fa4bc301ff5ef2eca5d8d82335a.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0131
17:07:13 web.1  | Rack::Lint::LintError: Content-Type header found in 304 response, not allowed
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/lint.rb:20:in `assert'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/lint.rb:651:in `block in check_content_type'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/lint.rb:647:in `each'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/lint.rb:647:in `check_content_type'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/lint.rb:58:in `_call'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/lint.rb:37:in `call'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/showexceptions.rb:24:in `call'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/chunked.rb:54:in `call'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:576:in `process_client'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:670:in `worker_loop'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:525:in `spawn_missing_workers'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
17:07:13 web.1  |   /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /resume-32740fa4bc301ff5ef2eca5d8d82335a.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0131
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET /welcome-32740fa4bc301ff5ef2eca5d8d82335a.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0147
17:07:13 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2014:17:07:13 -0400] "GET %2Fassets%2Fapplication-c17db73b14421ee3a4d7e97bd3a6041c.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 68757 0.0217
```

Every **other page reload** I get 500 internal error assets not found:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/assets/application-ddb2488b062b582487dc9a71475f69b3.css?body=1 
GET http://localhost:5000/assets/application-89761eef2e06fafdfbe675623cff99d7.js?body=1
```

Comment: look at the encoding there - `%2Fassets%2Fapplication-c17db73b14421ee3a4d7e97bd3a6041c.js` how are you requesting that file?

Comment: @seven but it is not in my control. I saw that. This happens on every other page reload. Something is spazzing. What can I do to force the proper encoding?

Comment: met the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it seems to be a bug (or not?). When assets was precompiled with:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile
```

and in `config/environments/development.rb` :

```
config.assets.digest = true
```

as it is `true` by default there in Rails 4.2 ([Release Notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#railties-notable-changes), [Pull Request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/15155)), you will be getting this bug in development environment, doesn't matter what server you use (I am getting it on both WEBrick and Thin). As I understand it, it tries to get precompiled assets from `/public/assets`, but fails because of

> Content-Type header found in 304 response, not allowed

or something like this.

You could avoid this behaviour by cleaning `/public/assets` every time you start development with:

```
bin/rake assets:clobber
```

or by turning off asset digests in development config:

```
config.assets.digest = false
```

or by turning off static assets serving in development config:

```
config.assets.digest = true
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

Comment: This was affecting me with the released rails 4.2. Did a bug get submitted about this bugme666? `config.assets.digest = false` made it use the normal development assets rather than those in the public folder.

Comment: @user1116573 No, sorry, didn't submit.